# run program when a command's output changes in bash

Tags: bash

For example lets say there is a program called `foo` and the program prints a new line whenever it wants. How can i run another program when `foo` prints a new line?

`foo` example:

```
while true; do
    echo hi
    sleep 1
done
```

*i cant edit `foo`*

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'new line'? Might be a good opportunity for a longer shell script, using a while loop. I wonder if you could do a one-liner using ```watch``` and ```diff``` and lots of pipe operators.

Comment: I dont think i can use a while loop because the foo program itself is somewhat a while loop, it produces output whenever it detects a change. I dont want to use watch because i dont want any delay.

Comment: Use the `read` builtin, see `help read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that I think will serve your purpose:

```
function my_function { while true; do read && "$@" ; done ; }
```

To run a program `prog` every time a program `foo` prints out a line, you can write this at the terminal:

```
foo | my_function prog
```

If you want to pass `arg1` and `arg2` as arguments to "prog", you can call it like so (thank you @Ulrich Eckhardt and @glenn jackman):

```
foo | my_function prog arg1 arg2
```

Comment: where should i call foo?

Comment: `foo | my_function "echo hello"` -- you pipe the output of `foo` into the program reacting to its output.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Oops, thanks for this addition! I will edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: I'd suggest: `my_function() { while true; do read && "$@"; done; }` then you can send any arbitrary arguments, even containing whitespace: `foo | my_function prog "arg the first" "arg the second"`

Comment: As @glennjackman suggested,  please edit your answer and replace `$@` by `"$@"`, or else I'll downvote you :-P

Comment: Yes, **always** quote `"$@"` unless you know _exactly_ what will happen if you don't.

Comment: What is a reasonable way to break out of the `while` loop? `$?` or set a variable or send a line with special content or use `set -e pipefail`  ?

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in comments, you can use `while read` to perform a loop iteration for each line of output from `foo`.

```sh
foo |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # maybe echo "$line"?
    echo "hi"
done
```

There are options to `read` to allow for a different input separator than newline.

This could be simplified a lot if you only really care about doing something when a line arrives, but not about the actual output before the newline. The `-r` option and the `IFS=` assignment help preserve the precise contents of `line` inside the loop (specifically, `IFS=` prevents the shell from trimming whitespace from the input value, and the `-r` option disables parsing of backslashes, which you generally don't want).